# what is the meaning of "1L << count" ? How is it that using this statement numbers beyond the range of "unsigned long long int? " can be printed?

Tags: c++, bitmap

What is the meaning of `1L << count`? How is it that using this expression numbers beyond the range of `unsigned long long int` can be printed?

```
fun_correct() {
    while(n>0) {
        if(n%2==0)
            count++;
        n/=2;
    }
    cout<<(1L << count);
}

fun_incorrect() {
    while(n>0) {
        if(n%2==0)
            count++;
        n/=2;
    }
    cout<<pow(2,count);
}
```

Comment: Bitwise shift I guess

Comment: `1L<<count` wouldn't produce valid results beyond the range of `unsigned long long`. It can produce invalid results, when shifting yields a negative number. If you want results in the range of `unsigned long long`, use `(1ULL << count)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you are using 1L it will give result of type long,
 if you want answer to be of unsigned long long use ULL, that will give you a 
 correct result,
 if you try to use L instead of ULL the compiler will give you warning
 (left shift count >= width of type),
 the output will be the maximum value of that type